# Adding a straight line and some other bits(text and formatting)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to make this figure. But I have achieved partially not completely, still missing the bits. This what I need to get(but failed)
[image]
Here is my code which does the work partially. But I don't seem to have any idea after that.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}



    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[ultra thick,cyan] (0,0) \foreach \k in {0,...,8} { let \n1={-2*mod(\k,2) + 1.0} in -- ++(0,\n1) -- ++(1,0)};
    \draw[densely dashed,cyan]   (3,0) -- + (0,1.5)      (5,0) -- + (0,1.5);
    \draw[<->]      (3,1.3) -- node[above] {$\Lambda$} + (2,0);
    \draw[red]   (1,1.5) node[above] {$z =0$} + (0,1.); 
    \draw[red]   (8,1.5) node[above] {$z = L$} + (0,1.);
    \draw[red]   (10,0) node[right] {$x = -a$};
    \draw[red]   (10,1) node[right] {$x = 0$};
    \draw[red]   (10,-2) node[right] {$x = -t$};
    \draw[ultra thick, cyan]  (9,1) -- + (1,0);
    \draw[ultra thick, cyan]  (0,-2) -- + (10,0);
    \draw[densely dashed, cyan]  (8,0) -- + (2,0);
    \draw[densely dashed,cyan]   (1,0) -- + (0,1.5); 
    \draw[densely dashed,cyan]   (8,0) -- + (0,1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

\begin{tikzpicture}This is what I am getting, missing some of the above info
[image]

Comment: What would you like to do as your next step, where you are getting stuck? Please be as specific as you can, to ease the work of people trying to help you.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay I would like to try to extend the nose or step at _z=L_ as shown in the picture and then label it _x=0_. Similarly, below that, with the dotted line _x=-a_.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Which I can do by  `\draw[ultra thick, cyan]  (9,1) -- + (1,0);`

Comment: Please do not edit questions in ways which make nonsense of existing answers.

Comment: @cfr I am really sorry for that. Not have much idea being a fool :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Answer to edited question

This just uses the same principle as my answer to the original question of naming and referencing nodes, with the addition of the `positioning` library.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [ultra thick, draw=cyan] (0,0) coordinate (o) \foreach \k in {0,...,8} { let \n1={-2*mod(\k,2) + 1.0} in -- ++(0,\n1) -- ++(1,0) coordinate (p\k)} -- ++(1,0) node [above=10pt,midway] {$n_1$} node (n2) [below=10pt,midway] {$n_2$} node (p9) [right, red] {$x=0$};
  \draw [densely dashed, draw=cyan]   (3,0) -- + (0,1.5)      (5,0) -- + (0,1.5) (o -| p7) -- (o -| p9.west) node (a) [right, red] {$x=-\alpha$}  (a -| n2) node (n3) [below=10pt] {$n_3$};
  \draw[<->]      (3,1.3) -- node (l) [above] {$\Lambda$} + (2,0);
  \node at (l |- n3) {Guiding layer};
  \draw[red]   (1,1.5) node[above] {$z =0$} + (0,1.); 
  \draw[red]   (8,1.5) node[above] {$z = L$} + (0,1.); 
  \draw[red]   (10,-2) node (t) [right] {$x = -t$};
  \path (t -| l) node [below=10pt] {Substrate layer};
  \draw[densely dashed,cyan]   (1,0) -- + (0,1.5); 
  \draw[densely dashed,cyan]   (8,0) -- + (0,1.5);
  \draw[ultra thick, cyan]  (0,-2) -- + (10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image: Extended with ns and things]

## Answer to original question

Something like this? This adds the two steps you mentioned in comments as causing difficulties, if I've understood correctly.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [ultra thick, draw=cyan] (0,0) coordinate (o) \foreach \k in {0,...,8} { let \n1={-2*mod(\k,2) + 1.0} in -- ++(0,\n1) -- ++(1,0) coordinate (p\k)} -- ++(2,0) node (p9) [right] {$x=0$};
  \draw [densely dashed, draw=cyan]   (3,0) -- + (0,1.5)      (5,0) -- + (0,1.5) (o -| p7) -- (o -| p9.west) node [right] {$x=\varnothing$};
  \draw[<->]      (3,1.3) -- node[above] {$\Lambda$} + (2,0);
  \draw[red]   (1,1.5) node[above] {$z =0$} + (0,1.); 
  \draw[red]   (8,1.5) node[above] {$z = L$} + (0,1.); 
  \draw[densely dashed,cyan]   (1,0) -- + (0,1.5); 
  \draw[densely dashed,cyan]   (8,0) -- + (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

This just works by naming the coordinates and nodes so they can be used later without specifying their actual coordinates.

[image: longer nose]

Comment: Thanks @cfr. But I have a one more piece the text and a straight line :)

Comment: @L.K. I completed the bits you said you were having trouble with. What's the problem with the straight line exactly? That should be easier than what you've got so far :-).

Comment: I did it, got close also but still the text like Guiding layer and substrate, how to add them? Also the _n1_, _n2_ and _n3_.

Comment: @L.K. Please see edit. Is it just me or do my reds come out differently from yours?

Comment: _n3_ is supposed to be below the straight line :) Anyways you got it, thanks

Comment: @L.K. So it is, but I'm sure you can do that bit of fine-tuning :-). It comes from switching back-and-forth to draw a diagram which has no meaning for me. That is, I don't know what it is about or what the labels represent, so it is very easy to get things slightly wrong. At least, such is my excuse and I'm sticking to it.